# React Native Release App.apk search metro server

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, apk, release

I have created a release of my android application. I have used Android Studio to create it, however, when I install the application it closes automatically. The error that appears is the following:
[image]

The specifications of my first application are as follows (app1):

```
-react native : 0.68.1
-buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
-minSdkVersion = 21
-compileSdkVersion = 31
-targetSdkVersion = 31
-buildGradle : 7.1.3
```

The same goes for my second app with the following specs (app2):

```
-react native : 0.67.4
-buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
-minSdkVersion = 21
-compileSdkVersion = 30
-targetSdkVersion = 30
-ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
-buildGradle : 4.2.2
```

What I need is a signed apk, I don't need a debug because it compiles. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. My solution:

```
  M1 Macbook Pro
  react-native: "0.68.1",
  buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
  minSdkVersion = 21
  compileSdkVersion = 31
  targetSdkVersion = 31
```

1. android/app/src/main/assests is not exist. I created one.
2. `npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle`
3. At this stage, the release process results in an error. I am delete all drawable-* folders under android/app/src/main/res. Don't delete android/app/src/main/res/drawable folder!.
4. in android folder `./gradlew assembleRelease` and success!

Answer (score 0):

The error log has clearly mentioned that the `index.android.bundle` file is the culprit here. To fix this, run the following command,

`npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle`

This will create the correct `index.android.bundle` file and you will be able to run the app.